# Fact table from the dimension table with 1 to 1 relationship

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, dimensions, ssas-tabular, fact-table

I have couple of tables which are dimension and facts. For example, I have Applications table (20 millions or rows and + 100 thounds every day), and I have Contracts table (5 millions or rows and + 10-20 thounds every day), both have common dictionaries (Customer, Bank, RiskResult, etc) for one contract can be more than one application, so for contract application is Dimension, and I need do analyze use Application attributes, but I need do analyze applications too, for example, how much applications was crated today, how much was deleted, difference between wish sum and actual sum in Application, etc. There is table transaction, where one contract have a lot of rows, so for Transation contract is dimension. What I did, in views for SSAS Tabular I create two tables from one, for Application table I craeted FactApplication where all SK all Dimensions and all sums, then I craeted DimApplicatiom where I placed all attributes, and then link them, but they have 1 to 1 relationship and I don't know how right is it? For cantracts I did the same.

Answer (score 0):

it'd be nice to have a more visual representation (ERD) of your raw tables and proposed Fact/Dim tables.

My understanding is that you have a "Credit Card Application" business process

I would have something like this:

- DimApplicant  (ApplicantSK (PK), FirstName, ...)
- FactApplication (ApplicationSK (PK), ApplicantSK(FK), ApplicationDateSK, ProcessingDuration, ApprovalStatus, CustomerSK (NULLABLE)(FK) (1 to N)..)
- DimContract (ContractSK, CustomerSK, ...) (Assuming there can be multiple contracts per Customer)
- DimCustomer (CustomerSK, FirstName...)